# Обрезать текст по количеству символов

Tags: text, javascript

Добрый вечер, подскажите пожалуйста, нужен такой скрипт. Например, есть заголовок.

"Здравствуй как твои дела?"

Нужно чтобы он обрезался например до 15 символом, а потом добавлялось троеточие, то есть.

"Здравствуй как тв..."

Answer (score 1):

```
//простите мой английский
function cutter (str, numOfChars, tail) {
  return str.substring(0, numOfChars)+tail;
}

console.log(cutter("Здравствуй как твои дела?", 15, '...'));
```

Comment: return str.substring(0, numOfChars)+tail;

меняем на 

    return (str.length > 15) ? str.substring(0, numOfChars)+tail : str;

Comment: return str.length<numOfChars ?  str : str.substring(0, numOfChars)+tail;

Comment: @dimka3210, почти один в один)))