# Обрезать значения в ячейках таблицы по количеству символов

Tags: javascript, jquery

В [интернетах](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/269236/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2) нашел такую функцию для обрезания текста по кол-ву символов в строке:

```
  function cutter (str, charsQuantity, dots) {
    return str.substring(0, charsQuantity) + dots;
  }
```

Хочу применить её к таблице, но стопорюсь на том, как вернуть каждой ячейке её обработанное значение.

Таблица, например, вот такая:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus, suscipit!</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, voluptate!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, accusantium?</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, minus!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Пробовал варианты типа варианта ниже и подобные, но явно где-то что-то не так пишу:

```
  $('table tr td').each( 
  function cutter () {
    return $(this).html().substring(0, 60) + '...';
  });
```

Comment: Чем плох replace ?

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich чего `replace`? Чего вы им хотите? Строки обрезать? Я думаю из названия самой функции понятно, что `replace` - замена

Comment: @lexxl твоя проблема лишь в том, что `$(this).html()` ты берешь значение и вырезаешь из него 60 символов, и троеточие добавляешь, НО, ты не присваиваешь текущему элементу новое значение. А просто возвращаешь его. если добавить `$(this).html($(this).html().substring(0, 60) + '...')` , то все заработает. PS. это как пример, без оптимизации

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, опередил, какашка

Comment: @Doofy чего сразу какашка то:)))

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев, ответ я долго готовил, удаляю, раз выполнен :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как пример из комментария:

```js
$('table tr td').each(function () {
  var current = $(this);
  current.html(current.html().substring(0, 60) + '...');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus, suscipit!</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eum, voluptate!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tenetur, accusantium?</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati, minus!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Причина не рабочего вашего кода в том, что вы не присваиваете новое значение ячейке, а просто (в пустую) выполняете обрезание строки.

Comment: а как бы так ещё ввести переменную, чтобы оригинальный текст можно было вывести по ховеру, например?

Comment: @lexxl `current.attr('title', current.html());` добавь например, ну получится, что на ячейке будет висеть подсказка, но лучше добавить все же какой нибудь блок внутри ячейки и уже на него вешать. Кстати лучше использовать current.text(), чтобы брать и устанавливать значения, а то, если будет хоть какой то `html` код, он тебе порежет закрывающиеся теги

Comment: `title` не очень удобно. хотелось бы создавать tooltip и в него помещать полный текст. ради кастомизации и прочего... но не могу оригинальный текст достать

Comment: @lexxl ну я когда так делал, мой компонент тултипа, брал значения из `data-title`. И выводилась кастомная подсказка

Comment: идею понял, спасибо